# Show indicator for two request

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have two requests. Each of them getting different data. I need to show an indicator when the all of two request is requesting. How i can do this?
this is my first request:

```
func productList(tableView:UITableView,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView,index1:Int,index2:Int,index3:Int){

    if product.count<=0{

        alamoFireManager?.request(.GET, "http://mobile.unimax.kz/api/Default1",parameters: ["type1id":index1,"type2id":index2,"type3id":index3,"name":"","userid":1089])
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    if let httpError = response.result.error {
                        switch(httpError.code){
                        case -1009:
                            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Нету интернета!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                            alert.show()
                            break
                        default:
                            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Повторите попытку!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                            alert.show()
                            break
                        }
                    } else { //no errors
                        let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                        print(statusCode)
                    }
                    spinner.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                    return

                }

                if let value = response.result.value {
                    // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                    let product = JSON(value)
                    for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in product {

                        let img:NSData
                        if let src=subJson["sphoto"].string{

                            if src.containsString("jpg"){
                                let range = src.startIndex.advancedBy(2)..<src.endIndex
                                let substring = src[range]
                                var urlString = "http://admin.unimax.kz/\(substring)"
                                urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
                                if let dataFromURL=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlString)!){
                                    img=dataFromURL
                                }
                                else{
                                    img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                        }

                        //Do something you want
                        let id=subJson["id"].int!
                        let name=subJson["name"].string!
                        let price=subJson["price"].int!
                        let description=subJson["description"].rawString()
                        self.product.append(Product(id:id,title: name, img: UIImage(data: img), price: price,desc:description!))
                    }
                    spinner.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
        }
    }
    else{
        spinner.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and this is my second request:

```
func makeGetFav(userID:Int,completionHandler: (responseObject:JSON) -> ()) {
    alamoFireManager?.request(.GET, "http://mobile.unimax.kz/api/Klientapi/?authid=\(userID)")
        .responseJSON {response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                if let httpError = response.result.error {
                    switch(httpError.code){
                    case -1009:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Нету интернета!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    default:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Повторите попытку!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    }
                } else { //no errors
                    let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                    print(statusCode)
                }
                return
            }
            completionHandler(responseObject: JSON(response.result.value!))
    }
}

func getFavs(userID:Int,tableView:UITableView,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView){
    getFavRequets(userID){(responseObject) in
        if responseObject != nil{
            self.favs.removeAll()
            self.localDB.clearFav()
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in responseObject {
                self.favs.append(FavModel(id: subJson["id"].int!, title: subJson["name"].string!, price: subJson["price"].int!))
            }
            spinner.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

there are i call it all:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    indicator.startAnimating()

    localDB.getUserInfo()
    getRequests.productList(tableView, spinner: indicator, index1: catalog1Index, index2: catalog2Index, index3: catalog3Index)
    if localDB.user.count>0{
        getRequests.getFavs(localDB.user[0].id, tableView: tableView, spinner: indicator)
    }
    localDB.checkCart(tableView, tabCtrl: tabBarController!)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very fast way to do it:

```
// global var

var isIndicatorActive : Bool = false


UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    indicator.startAnimating()
    self.isIndicatorActive = true
```

In the line before each `alamoFireManager?.request` you call :

```
if isIndicatorActive == false {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        indicator.startAnimating()
        self.isIndicatorActive = true
}
```

And after each line `spinner.stopAnimating()` add:

```
self.isIndicatorActive = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to using single network activity indicator and keep a counter which keep track of network activity within the application. I know my answer is more in text, but looking at your code it seems you can implement the following.

0 indicates no activity indicator.

As soon as a new activity starts, increment the counter do a check if counter is greater than 0 then show the indicator.

Decrement the counter when the activity task finishes. On decrement keep a check if counter is 0 then set the indicator visibility to false.

PS: Don't forget to increment/decrement in sync blocks. You may use objc_sync_enter(..) and objc_sync_exit(..) methods for this.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can control it using a singleton to start and stop it according to the number of running requests:

```
class NetworkActivityIndicator: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = NetworkActivityIndicator()

    private override init() {
    }

    var count = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.updateIndicator()
        }
    }

    private func updateIndicator() {
        if count > 0 {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        } else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    }
}
```

The you simply call `NetworkActivityIndicator.sharedInstance.count += 1` just before the request and `NetworkActivityIndicator.sharedInstance.count += 1`  when you get the response

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to add two variables to your class that indicate whether the associated request is complete, and then to create a function that stops the spinner only if both the variables indicate the calls are complete.

if you want to use the class for more than one ViewController then I suggest adding a struct-enum combo to organise the variables that are indicating which requests are currently underway.

eg

```
class GetRequests {

    var productsLoaded = false
    var favoritesLoaded = false

    func stopSpinnerIfNeeded(spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView) {
         if productsLoaded && favoritesLoaded {
             spinner.stopAnimating()
             spinner.hidden = true
         }
    }


    func productList(tableView:UITableView,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView,index1:Int,index2:Int,index3:Int){

    defer {
        productsLoaded = true
        stopSpinnerIfNeeded(spinner)
    }

    if product.count<=0{

        alamoFireManager?.request(.GET, "http://mobile.unimax.kz/api/Default1",parameters: ["type1id":index1,"type2id":index2,"type3id":index3,"name":"","userid":1089])
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                if let httpError = response.result.error {
                    switch(httpError.code){
                    case -1009:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Нету интернета!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    default:
                        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Ошибка",message: "Повторите попытку!!",delegate: nil,cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                        alert.show()
                        break
                    }
                } else { //no errors
                    let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                    print(statusCode)
                }
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                return

            }

            if let value = response.result.value {
                // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                let product = JSON(value)
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in product {

                    let img:NSData
                    if let src=subJson["sphoto"].string{

                        if src.containsString("jpg"){
                            let range = src.startIndex.advancedBy(2)..<src.endIndex
                            let substring = src[range]
                            var urlString = "http://admin.unimax.kz/\(substring)"
                            urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
                            if let dataFromURL=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlString)!){
                                img=dataFromURL
                            }
                            else{
                                img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        img=NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/Images/domalak.png")!)!
                    }

                    //Do something you want
                    let id=subJson["id"].int!
                    let name=subJson["name"].string!
                    let price=subJson["price"].int!
                    let description=subJson["description"].rawString()
                    self.product.append(Product(id:id,title: name, img: UIImage(data: img), price: price,desc:description!))
                }
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    else{

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

    func getFavs(userID:Int,tableView:UITableView,spinner:UIActivityIndicatorView){
getFavRequets(userID){(responseObject) in
        if responseObject != nil{
            self.favs.removeAll()
            self.localDB.clearFav()
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in responseObject {
                self.favs.append(FavModel(id: subJson["id"].int!, title: subJson["name"].string!, price: subJson["price"].int!))
            }

            favoritesLoaded = true
            stopSpinnerIfNeeded(spinner)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everybody for help. I solve it like this:

```
func makeReuest1(){
    if localDB.user.count>0{
        getRequests.getFavs(localDB.user[0].id)
    }
    makeRequest2()
}

func makeRequest2(){
    getRequests.productList(tableView, spinner: indicator, index1: catalog1Index, index2: catalog2Index, index3: catalog3Index)
}
```